# MPMoviePlayerViewController not working

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, mpmovieplayercontroller, modalviewcontroller

I have been roaming the internet for a solution I really don't know what am I doing wrong. I have been with this problem a few days now. I save the video at the following path that should be accessible to the application (Right?)

```
//NSDocumentDirectory doesn't work either.
NSArray *newPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSMoviesDirectory,
                                                       NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *moviesDirectory = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/WebSurg", 
                                                     [newPath objectAtIndex:0]];
// Check if the directory already exists
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:moviesDirectory]) {
    // Directory does not exist so create it
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:moviesDirectory 
                      withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
}
```

I show the contents of this directory in a tableView in the application. When a row is tapped it should play the video. But it doesn't. It shows me the MPMoviePlayerViewController modal view and then hides it after probably what is 1 second. This is the code I use to play it:
I tried two ways of getting the path to no avail.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSArray *moviesPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSMoviesDirectory, 
                                                              NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *moviesDirectory = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/WebSurg", 
                                                       [moviesPath objectAtIndex:0]];
    NSString *movie = [self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *moviePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", 
                                                         moviesDirectory, movie];
    NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath]; 
    NSLog(@"MOVIEPATH: %@", moviePath);

    NSString *alternatePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", 
                                            [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], movie];
    NSURL *alternateMoviePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];
    movieViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:alternateMoviePath];
    movieViewController.moviePlayer.movieSourceType= MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
    NSLog(@"Movie Load State: %d", [[movieViewController moviePlayer] loadState]);
    NSLog(@"Alternate movie Path: %@", alternatePath);
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:movieViewController];
    [movieViewController.moviePlayer play];
    [self checkAndPlay];
}

- (void) checkAndPlay {
    if ([[self.movieViewController moviePlayer] loadState] == MPMovieLoadStateUnknown) { 
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:
                               @selector(checkAndPlay) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    } else {
        [self.movieViewController setModalTransitionStyle:
                                   UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
        [self presentModalViewController:movieViewController animated:YES];
    }
}
```

And these are the results of the console:

```
2012-10-08 10:14:52.392 WebsurgTemplates[3722:17903] MOVIEPATH: /Users/THISISME/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/E075DBE3-BFEA-4F6A-9DFA-2CC912E14863/Movies/WebSurg/FirstVideo.mp4
2012-10-08 10:14:52.459 WebsurgTemplates[3722:17903] Movie Load State: 0
2012-10-08 10:14:52.460 WebsurgTemplates[3722:17903] Alternate movie Path: /Users/THISISME/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/E075DBE3-BFEA-4F6A-9DFA-2CC912E14863/WebsurgTemplates.app/FirstVideo.mp4
```

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions and help!!

**UPDATE**

I made no progress so far. I managed to log some other data to the console, some info that may help more at solving this problem. I tried to make a blank project taking the direct download of the video as link to play the video but it didn't work. What happens is exactly the same thing. jaydee3 said that maybe it was due because I had probably no access to NSMoviesDirectory. So I changed to NSDocumentDirectory but that didn't solve the problem. I checked that the file exists and the format in which it is saved so it can be readable by the player. Still it doesn't work. I don't know what am I doing wrong. Thanks again for the suggestions/help.

Here the results of the debug. more complete:

```
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:moviePath]) {
    NSLog(@"FILE EXISTS");
    CFStringRef fileExtension = (__bridge CFStringRef) [moviePath pathExtension];
    CFStringRef fileUTI = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, fileExtension, NULL);

    if (UTTypeConformsTo(fileUTI, kUTTypeImage)) NSLog(@"It's an image");
    else if (UTTypeConformsTo(fileUTI, kUTTypeMovie)) NSLog(@"It's a movie");
    else if (UTTypeConformsTo(fileUTI, kUTTypeText)) NSLog(@"It's text");
}

RESULTS
[6343:17903] MOVIEPATH: /Users/myname/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/E075DBE3-BFEA-4F6A-9DFA-2CC912E14863/Documents/FirstVideo.mp4
[6343:17903] FILE EXISTS
[6343:17903] It's a movie
```

Comment: if you set a breakpoint in your "`checkAndPlay`" method, is it being called twice when the table cell is selected?

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. From what I can tell with the breakpoint is that it gets called many times. But I don't know why. The Movie Load State does not change as it should...

Comment: if you look at the backtrace (i.e. the events that happen that cause "`checkAndPlay`" to get called) you might be able to get an idea of what's going on.  Theoretically, if I understand your code correctly, it should only be called once, when the table cell is selected. Yes?

Comment: I'm not quite sure about the `NSMoviesDirectory` on iOS. Have your tried the same code with the documents directory? That one is accessible for sure.

Comment: @jaydee3: I will try and keep you posted. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: Have you checked if the PATH is really there(is the movie included to the targets) the fast closing of it is because it does not find a file.. the modalview appears, looks for a file, closes after running file, if the file is not found it directly closes. I am also curious about the NSMovie Path on iOS as well. You have to have a single NSString with the filepath and then pass the path to the movieplayercontroller PathForRessource

Comment: The movie is a resource that changes all the time (As the tableview will be updated with contents of the downloaded videos) so I don't include it on the targets. But it should work. @jaydee3 I tried with the NSDocumentDirectory but it keeps doing the same thing and I get the same path (With documents) on the debugger.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann actually it is normal that the checkAndPlay method gets called many times since it is a recursive method. I had forgotten about that. So it is quite normal. It gets called depending on the status of the video. in this case if the status of the loadState is 0 (UNKNOWN) then it will try again. This is mainly to fix a bug that comes often with the MPMovieViewController class.

Comment: how is your `movieViewController` variable defined!? is it weak!? than your movieViewController might be nil right after the initialization. have you checked your movieViewController object?

Comment: @jaydee3 No it is a Strong property. I already checked that as well. :-( I don't understand what is wrong. It seems the controller can't get the movie file. Even if it is found on NSDocument and that it exists and that it is a movie file type!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I managed to solve the problem and find the culprit.

In a brief note it was because the downloaded movie wasn't being saved properly (I am currently investigating the possible reasons why). And because of this the player was trying to play a file that existed, was in the correct format and the correct name but that was empty. I found this out by logging all the file sizes after download and transfer and play.

Now being more descriptive the issue was that I was downloading the movie to the `NSCachesDirectory` and then saving it to the `NSDocumentDirectory`. I found this because I started to wonder if it really found the file and if the file was "edible". It now plays the movie fine as I download it directly to the `NSDocumentDirectory`. Now I have to solve just in case the connection goes down. As saving in the `NSCachesDirectory` solved that automatically. I am open to suggestions on that. here is the code that didn't work to transfer the data from the `NSCachesDirectory` to `NSDocumentDirectory`:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
                // HERE I changed NSCachesDirectory to NSDocumentDirectory fixed it
                            (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *cachesDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *downloadPath = [cachesDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                                                  @"DownloadedVideo.mp4"];
NSArray *newPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
                                  (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *moviesDirectory = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", 
                                                [newPath objectAtIndex:0]];
self.downloadOperation = [ApplicationDelegate.mainDownloader downloadVideoFrom:
                                    @"http://www.blablabla.web/iphone/download.php"                                    
                                            toFile:downloadPath];
```